# jQuery onclick show next hide first visible div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of divs and I only want to display 4 at a time.  By default you see 1,2,3,4 when you click on next you should see 2,3,4,5 if you then click next you should see 3,4,5,6 and if you click prev you should see 1,2,3,4, if you click prev initially I would like nothing to happen. and when you get to the end I would like nothing to happen on next click.

Currently this is what I have but it seems to be a fair way off?, ([click here](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/dRfb4/4/)),

```
    <div class="testwrap">
        <div class="testtitle">
            <h3>Test title 1</h3>
        </div>
    <span style="float:left" id="prev">prev</span>

        <div class="testclass test1">1</div>
        <div class="testclass test2">2</div>
        <div class="testclass test3">3</div>
        <div class="testclass test4">4</div>
        <div class="testclass test5">5</div>
        <div class="testclass test6">6</div>
        <div class="testclass test7">7</div>
        <div class="testclass test8">8</div>
        <div class="testclass test9">9</div>
        <div class="testclass test10">10</div>
    <span style="float:right" id="next">next</span>

    </div>

    <script>
    $('.testclass:gt(3)').hide();

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        var first = $('.testwrap').children('.testclass:visible:first');
        first.prevAll('.testclass:lt(1)').show();
        first.prev().nextAll('.testclass').hide()
    });

    $('#next').click(function() {
        var last = $('.testwrap').children('.testclass:visible:last');
        last.nextAll('.testclass:lt(1)').show();
        last.next().prevAll('.testclass').hide();
    });
    </script>

    <style>
    .testwrap {
        float: left;
        background: orange;
        width: 500px;
    }

    .testclass {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 yellow;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: left;
        font-size: 28px;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 7px 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .testtitle {
        float:left;
        display:inline;
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: why have prev button when you don't want anything to happen ?

Comment: Only the first time eg initially there is no prev but when you click next  prev becomes relevant.

Comment: you mentioned , if you have 3,4,5,6 and you click prev , it should see 1,2,3,4 ideally would'nt it be 2,3,4,5 ? whats the rationale behind this ?

Comment: Yes I meant if you clicked prev when u were on 2,3,4,5 instead of next but I can see how it could interpreted like you did. I will see I I can come up with a better wy to word this to make it clearer.

Comment: would u b comfortable with scroll bar ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on your next click..get all visible from first...and display `.testclass:lt(4)`.. and on prev click...get all visible from last...and display `.testclass:lt(4)`

try this

```
$('.testclass:gt(3)').hide();

$('#prev').click(function() {
  var first = $('.testwrap').children('.testclass:visible:last');
  if(first.prevAll('.testclass:lt(4)').length == 4){  //updated check if count of total displayed div is 4.. then sho() and hide() 
    first.prevAll('.testclass:lt(4)').show();
    first.prev().nextAll('.testclass').hide()
  }
});

$('#next').click(function() {
  var last = $('.testwrap').children('.testclass:visible:first');
  if(last.nextAll('.testclass:lt(4)').length == 4){ //updated
    last.nextAll('.testclass:lt(4)').show();
    last.next().prevAll('.testclass').hide();
  }
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/dRfb4/6/)

I added one more `<div>` to check for the logic.. you can try it out in..

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/dRfb4/12/)

Comment: Yes this works thanks. Is it possible to have 4 always showing? And also disable prev initially as if u keep clicking it u lose the divs and can't get them back?

Comment: There is no need to check condition like `('.testclass:lt(4)').length == 4`, `lt-selector` automatically matches the elements passing in that function(`lt`). Refer http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: @RohanKumar no i am using the condition  to check the length so that the further click on prev and next is not interpreted and NOT for displaying the divs.. if length is 4 then prev and next click will do nothing as the OP said .. he wants to disable the link once it reach the last div...

Comment: @bipen Yes but, I think this will enough to check it `if(first.prevAll('.testclass:lt(4)').length)` and `if(last.nextAll('.testclass:lt(4)').length)`

Comment: @RohanKumar i think you are not getting me.. :)... try it out in my updated fiddle ... like you said... and i think you  'll notice.. anyways thanks.. :)

Comment: commented on your post.. check it out.. :)

Answer (score 2):

For such a pagination I would use a variable containing the current active page and the slice method to display the requested range:

```
var cP = 0 /* current page */, 
    vP = 4 /* how many page links should be visible */;

$('.testclass:gt('+(vP-1)+')').hide();

$('#prev').click(function() {
    if(cP > 0) { 
        cP--;
        $('.testclass').hide();
        $('.testclass').slice(cP,cP+vP).show();
    }
});

$('#next').click(function() {
    if(cP < $('.testclass').length-vP ) { 
        cP++;
        $('.testclass').hide();
        $('.testclass').slice(cP,cP+vP).show();
    }
});
```

You find a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZEGt/) here.

Comment: This is the most readable solution so far. to make it more general, put first line below var initializations and make gt(3) value use vP - 1.

Comment: Is it possible to add rotating effect in this code snippet? I mean user can see that first icon is disappear and displaying the last one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.testclass:gt(3)').hide();

$('#prev').click(function() {
    var first = $('.testwrap').children('.testclass:visible:last');
    if(first.prevAll('.testclass:lt(4)').length==4)
    {
        first.prevAll('.testclass:lt(4)').show();
        first.prev().nextAll('.testclass').hide()
    }
});

$('#next').click(function() {
    var last = $('.testwrap').children('.testclass:visible:first');
    if(last.nextAll('.testclass:lt(4)').length==4)
    {
         last.nextAll('.testclass:lt(4)').show();
         last.next().prevAll('.testclass').hide();
    }
});
```

Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dRfb4/13/

Comment: right... but thn OP said `By default you see 1,2,3,4 when you click on next you should see 2,3,4,5 if you then click next you should see 3,4,5,6`.. in your case that is `1,2,3,4` then `5,6,7,8` and so on.. to check this i had to check for the length... :):)